# How can I convert multiple similar instances of javascript into one global function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, global, playback

On my music improvising website, I've created a list of rhythms that a user can choose from. When they click the button associated with each rhythm, two things happen: 1) the PNG of the rhythm fills the "display" div, and 2) the rhythm plays.

I've figured out code that allows this to happen... but only the #1 part (filling the display with the image) is a global function. #2 (the playing of the rhythm) is still an individual function for each rhythm. Considering that I have over 100 rhythms in total, this ends up being a lot of code.

Any suggestions on how I can convert the play() function into a global function? (Ideally, I'd even be able to add a play/pause toggle to the mix, but that's another question.)

Many thanks!

Right now, the play() function is repeated for each rhythm (>100 in total):

```
<section class="allRhythms">
   <h6>Tap play to listen. Tap number to select.</h6>
        <div class="RM_rhythm">
            <audio id="2.1" preload='none'>
            <source src='../audio/2.1.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='../audio/2.1.ogg' type='audio/ogg' /></audio>
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('2.1').play();"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
            <a href="#" class="button">2-1</a>
            <img src="../images/RM-2.1.png" width="172" height="60" alt="2-1">
        </div>
        <div class="RM_rhythm">
            <audio id="2.2" preload='none'>
            <source src='../audio/2.2.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='../audio/2.2.ogg' type='audio/ogg' /></audio>
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('2.2').play()"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
            <a href="#" class="button">2-2</a>
            <img src="../images/RM-2.2.png" width="172" height="60" alt="2-2">
        </div>
        <div class="RM_rhythm">
            <audio id="2.3" preload='none'>
            <source src='../audio/2.3.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='../audio/2.3.ogg' type='audio/ogg' /></audio>
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('2.3').play()"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
            <a href="#" class="button">2-3</a>
            <img src="../images/RM-2.3.png" width="172" height="60" alt="2-3">
        </div>
</section>
```

This global script fills the div with the image of the selected rhythm:

```
<!-- fill currentRhythm_A -->   
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').on('click', function() {
        var imagewanted = $(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('img').attr("src");
        $('.currentRhythm_A').html("<img src='" + imagewanted + "' />");
        var currentlabel = $(this).closest('.RM_rhythm').find('audio').attr("id");
        $('#currentLabelA').html(currentlabel);
        $('#playA').html("<source src='../audio/" + currentlabel + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /><source src='../audio/" + currentlabel + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg' />");
        $('#playA').load(); 

   });
});
</script>
```

This div fills with the image:

```
<div class="currentSelection">
    <div class="selectedLabelA" id="currentLabelA">A</div>
    <div class="selectedRhythm currentRhythm_A" id="currentRhythm_A"><img src="../images/RM-0.1.png" width="172" height="60" alt="0-1" /></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You want a javascript or a jQuery answer ??

Comment: Which do you think would be the better way to go?

Comment: it depends first if all the rest of your code is in jQuery or not, and also your degree of mastery on JS or jQuery. But I point out that you have not put jQuery in your Tags, so I wonder why: is it because you want to exclude any answer in jQuery? And anyway the function you show is generic

Comment: I'm open to jQuery. Frankly, I don't have much deep knowledge in either. Mostly I borrow code from stackoverflow and try to adapt it and learn something.

Comment: anyway the function you show is generic